# why is the count($array) function not counting?

Tags: php, arrays, count

I checked if the variable is an array. 
I can return desired elements out of the array by going `$array[n]`;

so that's all good.

but in the following code I don't get the amount of elements returned if I go `count($array)`. `sizeof($array)` won't do the job either.

```
    //converting string $messages to array: 
    $messagesArr =  explode("<hr/>", $messages);

            if (is_array($messagesArr )){print("<p style='color:red'>Array OK<p>");}
        else {print("<p style='color:red'>Array not OK<p>");}

    $secondElement = $messagesArr[1]; 
        print("<p style='color:red'>second element is: $tweedeElem<p>"); 
            // This  one actually outputs the desired second element of the array

            $amountMess = count($messagesArr);
    print("<p style='color:red'>the amount of messages is: $amountMess<p>");
```

Comment: Are you talking about `$berichtenArr`? If yes, where is it defined?

Comment: Where is `$berichtenArr` being set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$amountMess = count($messagesArr);
```

`$berichtenArr` != `$messagesArr`

Comment: ouch i though I had the translation down but in the original the count argument is the same. Still the count function will not do it

Comment: What exactly does not work? Switch on full PHP error reporting and check for notices or warnings. Output a `var_dump($messagesArr)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you've pasted, you're storing the messages in `$messagesArr` but calling count on another variable `$berichtenArr`. What does that variable contain? Seems you have a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `$berichtenArr`:

```
$berichtenArr = array(blahhhh, foooo, barrrr);
```

Otherwise `count($berichtenArr)` won't return anything useful.